# Детали работы с sourse-map при верстке

Tags: вёрстка, sourcemap

Не могу понять как происходит работа с **source-map** в реальной жизни. Знаменитая статья на хабре не удовлетворяет меня полностью.

1. Source-map это файл, который связан с объединенным и минифицированным файлом.. Т.е. по сути(внешняя структура) получается, что это объединенный файл, до минификации?
2. Если мне надо, допустим, изменить стиль кнопок, я открываю файл карты, редактирую его и эти изменения автоматически вносятся в минифицированный файл? Просто иначе я не понимаю в чём его преимущества, почему тогда не держать там объединенный файл css и не минифицировать его заново после изменений.
3. Почему встречаются запросы типо source-map в Safari или Chrome? Это именно браузерная "фишка" отладчиков и она как-то привязана к браузерам?

---

PS стаковерфлоу говорит что я могу опубликовать вопрос без метки, а затем попросить создать метку, и не даёт опубликовать вопрос без метки. Поставил метку "верстка", поправьте если что не так.